# Sublime Text 3 JavaScript Autocomplete

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I use SublimeText3 and I get the function of autocomplete only for HTML and CSS but not for JavaScript. Why is this? And how can I get JavaScript autocomplete?

Comment: Are you looking for native methods, or your own code?  Either way, try using the `ctrl+space` keyboard shortcut-- that usually opens the autocomplete for me.

Answer (score 0):

there is Javascript Autocompletion, but it seem not up to date with document. https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Completions

Comment: -------------- 
 Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)